# ASP.NET Core 2 IFormCollection returning StringValues

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

Recently the IFormCollection in the platform I'm building started returning values of the type Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.StringValues. when it used to return strings.
The controllers were made with strings in mind and now that are a lot of forms that are not working.

Is there any explanation to this, or a way to revert it?

Comment: Can you please share your code? Also, do you have [FromBody] attribute added with input parameters of POST and PUT requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware ASP.NET Core's `IFormCollection` has always been a collection of `StringValues`. The reason is simple: multiple values can be posted for any particular key, making it potentially impossible to set the value if the type was merely *string*. There is no way to "revert" this. Change your code accordingly.

Or, better yet, *stop using `IFormCollection`*. Bind to strongly-typed models. That's always the best way.

Comment: It is worth noting that for very complex and dynamic forms using unobtrusive validation, model biding can be a challenge and so IFormCollection can offer a simple way to view all data on form post

Comment: I've handled very large object hierarchies in a single form post. Model-binding is always better. You're going to have to unwrap that data into some kind of object anyways to do anything useful with it. Might as well, let the framework handle that for you so you can focus on the business end.

Answer (score 2):

For others coming here also confused by seeing `IFormCollection` giving `StringValues`. You may be familiar with .NET Frameworks `FormCollection` class, which gives strings. The reason for the change is valid and explained by @Chris Pratt in his answer here.

To make `IFormCollection` and `StringValues` feel familiar again consider any of these simple extensions:

```
// Example: var name = collection["name"].FirstOrNull();
// Equal to (.NET Framework): var name = collection["name"];
public static string FirstOrNull(this StringValues values)
{
    if (values.Count > 0)
    {
        return values[0];
    }
    return null;
}

// Example: var name = collection["name"].FirstOr("John Doe");
// Equal to (.NET Framework): var name = collection["name"] ?? "John Doe";
public static string FirstOr(this StringValues values, string fallback)
{
    if (values.Count > 0)
    {
        return values[0];
    }
    return fallback;
}

// Example: var name = collection.ValueOrFallback("name", "John Doe");
// Equal to (.NET Framework): var name = collection["name"] ?? "John Doe";
public static string ValueOrFallback(this IFormCollection collection, string key, string fallback)
{
    if (collection[key].Count > 0)
    {
        return collection[key][0];
    }
    return fallback;
}
```

Also consider the built-in `TryGetValue`:

```
if (collection.TryGetValue("name", out var name))
{
    // at least one name did exist
}
```

Alt.

```
var name = collection.TryGetValue("name", out var names) ? names[0] : "John Doe";
```