# Form Fields being returned as arrays instead of values

Tags: asp.net-core

i have a form being posted to a app.MapPost methods.  this is working but for some reason the fields in the form are being returned as arrays instead of single values?

what could be causing this?

the request.Form value is `[{"key":"test_input","value":["test"]}]`

Program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var app = builder.Build();
app.MapRazorPages();

app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");

app.MapPost("/posttest", (HttpRequest request) =>
{
    return request.Form;
});

app.Run();
```

Index.cshtml

```
@page
@model WebApplication1.Pages.IndexModel
@{
}

<h1>app.MapPost Testing</h1>
<form method="post" action="/posttest">
    <input type="text" name="test_input"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because IFormCollection.Item returns StringValues not a single string value. This answer explains it very well -
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51089693/1181846